# how to create a custom profile page

Tags: views, 7, theming

I want to create a page which have user details like Name, user picture, designation, about , user's social link, these details should in left side and user uploaded images in right site both things in a single page.
Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use custom templates for user profile pages.

Basically, you have to copy the **user-profile.tpl.php** from **/modules/user** into your theme directory, clear the cache and edit it according to your needs.

To see the list of available variables to use inside the tpl.php file, look here: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user-profile.tpl.php/7

I think that another possible approach (that doesn't require coding) would be to use Panels + Views